# How do I set up python intepreter in VS code on Mac OS 13.4.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

After I post the path of the project obtained by the command pipenv --venv into the command palette of vs code, it is supposed to create a new vs code settings file according to this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHux0gMZ3Eg&t=3158s](https://stackoverflow.com) (timestamp 20 mins) however in my case, none of the changes are taking place. What could be the possible problem or solution for this?

I tried creating a new directory which did not work. I even tried entering `/bin/python3.11` as the path of the interpreter but it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the selected interpreter: open the Command Palette: Cmd + Shift + P on Mac. Then type “Python: Select Interpreter”. Alternatively, you can click on the current interpreter in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting your project with a Python virtual environment.

You can create a virtual environment by using commands

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv. # create virtual environment
$ .venv/bin/activate # used virtual environment
(.venv) $
```

After using this command, VS Code will also suggest setting the Python interpreter to the location of `.venv` folder.

> Reference: [VScode Python Environment Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)